# Using variables from one script in another script in a string. Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the below not work when run. I am trying to declare a variable in **Script 1** I thought defining the variable outside would allow it to be global. I will say this is for a chrome application, I have the necessary permission in my manifest and I have the correct script for Jquery in my HTML.

```
   var userName;`
```

and then use that in **script 2** `

```
   var text = 'Hello' + userName + 'This is a test'`
```

Full Code

**Script 1**

```
   var userName;
    var userEmail;
    var userTeamName;
    function currentUrl() {
      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        chrome.tabs.query({
          active: true,
          currentWindow: true
        }, function(tabs) {
          resolve(tabs[0].url)
        })
      })
    }
    function userIdfromUrl(url) {
      var parts = url.split('/')
      return parts[parts.length - 1]
    }
    var authorizationToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    function myapiRequest(endpoint, options) {
        $.ajax($.extend({}, {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        $('.Name').html(data.user.name);
        $('.Email').html(data.user.email);
        $('.Address').html(data.user.teams[0].name);
    },
        url: "https://api.myapi.com/" + endpoint,
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorizationToken,
          "Accept": "application/vnd.myapi+json;version=2"
        }
      },
      options));
    }
    currentUrl()
      .then(function (url) {
        return userIdfromUrl(url)
      })
      .then(function (userId) {
        return myapiRequest('users/' + userId + '?include%5B%5D=contact_methods&include%5B%5D=teams')
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.user.name)
        console.log(data.user.email)
        console.log(data.user.teams[0].name)
        jsonData = data.user.name;
of the function
      })
        .then(function(data) {
                userName = data.user.name;
                userEmail = data.user.email;
                userTeamName = data.user.teams[0].name;
      })
```

**Script 2**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#contact-submit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var btn = $(e.target);
            btn.attr("disabled", "disabled"); // disable button
        var url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        var text = 'Hello' + userName + 'This is a test'
        $.ajax({
          data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
            "text": text
          }),
          dataType: 'json',
          processData: false,
          type: 'POST',
          url: url
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: use `window.username`

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: Are you sure you are not importing the files in a wrong order?

Comment: **username** is filled in the **currentUrl** asyncronous call. Hence, you can use it only after the variable is ready.

Comment: What "*doesn't work*"? Are you getting an error or are you getting "HelloundefinedThis is a test" in `text` variable's value? If it is the latter, the ajax call that populates `username` hasn't completed yet.

Comment: @adiga I reproduced and was getting "HelloundefinedThis is a test" in console.